# Cancel Insert if inner query find nothing

Tags: mysql, insert

I got the following query :

```
INSERT INTO contracts_settings (contract_id, setting_id, setting_value)
VALUES (:contract_id, (
    SELECT  setting_id
    FROM    settings
    WHERE   setting_type = :setting_type
        AND setting_name = :setting_name
    LIMIT   1
), :setting_value)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE setting_value = :setting_value
```

The value with the prefix `:` is replaced with data using PHP `PDO::bindBalue`.

If the inner query find nothing (it return NULL) but also INSERT a NULL statement. How to avoid that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `INSERT ... VALUES` syntax to **[`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)**:

```
INSERT INTO contracts_settings 
  (contract_id, setting_id, setting_value)
SELECT 
    :contract_id,
    setting_id,
    :setting_value
FROM  settings
WHERE setting_type = :setting_type
  AND setting_name = :setting_name
LIMIT   1

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    setting_value = :setting_value ;
```

Comment: If the `SELECT` return nothing, the query will fail ?

Comment: If the `SELECT` returns 0 rows, the `INSERT` will insert 0 rows (so, nothing).

Comment: Thanks you. Working like a charm ! You tought me something me sir !